# Copy launch configuration to launch template in aws-cli

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli, autoscaling

Does anyone know of a way to copy an AWS Autoscaling Group **launch configuration** to an EC2 **launch template**?

There appears to be a [way to do this in the AWS web console](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/copy-launch-config.html), but I can't find a command for this in the aws-cli.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will work but may be try using describe-launch-configurations output as your template data?

Comment: We use this (from CFN), but it can be adapted to be called from a shell script: https://github.com/ab77/cfn-generic-custom-resource/blob/master/README.md#create_launch_template_from_configuration